# How to get all registred 'browser:resource' in Plone

Tags: plone

How can I get all registered `browser:resource` and `browser:resourceDirectory` from the component registry?

I've looked in different places trying to discover what kind of components are created by the zcml directive `browser:resource` and found `Products.Five.browser.metaconfigure` with a `registerAdapter` call:

```
handler('registerAdapter', factory, (layer,), Interface, name, _context.info)
```

This means it will register an adapter which requires `(layer,)` and provides `Interface`, but calling the following doesn't work (it returns a component that is not a browser resource):

```
from zope.publisher.interfaces.browser import IDefaultBrowserLayer
zope.component.getAdapters((IDefaultBrowserLayer,), Interface)
```

I'm not sure but it seems `getAdapters` needs an instance. I don't want to query zope.component but to get registered adapters.

I found in `zope.interface.interfaces` a method `lookupAll(required, provided)` that looks like what I want but I couldn't find where it's implemented so I don't know how to call it.

Answer (score 2):

`zope.component.getAdapters()` *does* need to be passed an instance. The [`zope.interface.registry.Components.getAdapters()` method](https://github.com/zopefoundation/zope.interface/blob/master/src/zope/interface/registry.py#L248) calls:

```
list(map(providedBy, objects))
```

where `providedBy` is `zope.interface.declarations.providedBy()`. All that `IDefaultBrowserLayer` provides is.. `zope.interface.IInterface` and `zope.interface.ISpecification`.

You'll need to pass in a dummy object that *provides* `IDefaultBrowserLayer` instead of passing in the interface directly.

```
from zope.publisher.interfaces.browser import IDefaultBrowserLayer
import zope.component
import zope.interface

class dummy(object):
    zope.interface.classProvides(IDefaultBrowserLayer)

zope.component.getAdapters((dummy,), zope.interface.Interface)
```

Comment: It works but do not extract all resources. Here is the script I have wrote from your answer: https://gist.github.com/toutpt/6351383 Could you please take a look ? Many adapters fails on getToolByName portal_membership because the dummy object is not a content. (this refert to stringterp adapts but I guess this is for extra adapters (not for resources)

Comment: Your approach looks correct; I only have code style comments; loose all the `pass` statements, use `while True:` and `break` on `StopIteration`, and I wouldn't use an `else:` suite for the `try`, just dedent that code block instead.